# ClassNotFoundException using wscompile task

Tags: java, web-services

We are using the wscompile ant task and getting classnotfound error.

```
[wscompile] RmiModeler error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org$soa$soap$UserService
[wscompile]     at com.sun.xml.rpc.processor.modeler.rmi.RmiModeler.modelPort(RmiModeler.java:685)
[wscompile]     at com.sun.xml.rpc.processor.modeler.rmi.RmiModeler.buildLiteralModel(RmiModeler.java:603)
[wscompile]     at com.sun.xml.rpc.processor.modeler.rmi.RmiModeler.buildModel(RmiModeler.java:457)
[wscompile]     at com.sun.xml.rpc.processor.config.ModelInfo.buildModel(ModelInfo.java:88)
[wscompile]     at com.sun.xml.rpc.processor.Processor.runModeler(Processor.java:63)
[wscompile]     at com.sun.xml.rpc.tools.wscompile.CompileTool.run(CompileTool.java:714)
[wscompile]     at com.sun.xml.rpc.util.ToolBase.run(ToolBase.java:43)
[wscompile]     at com.sun.xml.rpc.tools.ant.Wscompile.execute(Wscompile.java:746)
[wscompile]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[wscompile]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
[wscompile]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[wscompile]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
[wscompile]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[wscompile]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[wscompile]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
[wscompile]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
[wscompile]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
[wscompile]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1366)
[wscompile]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[wscompile]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1249)
[wscompile]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:801)
[wscompile]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:218)
[wscompile]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
[wscompile]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
[wscompile]
[wscompile] CAUSE:
```

The interesting thing this is this happens only when the no of services goes up, meaning the no class file go up... I think there should be some setting for the  memory in ant or wscompile?

```
<wscompile server="true"
               keep="true"
               features="documentliteral"
               sourceBase="${gen.dir}/wscompile/src"
               nonClassDir="${gen.dir}/wscompile/nd"
               base="${gen.dir}/wscompile/classes"
               model="${gen.dir}/wscompile/user-model.gz"
               xPrintStackTrace="true"
               verbose="true"
               config="build/config-user_service.xml">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement path="dist/lib/$javacode.jar}"/>
      </classpath>
    </wscompile>
```

when the size of javacode.jar is 52MB this works and the size grows to say 53MB the above error is generated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's very likely the cause of this is your PermGen is running out of memory. PermGen stores the meta-info about each class, so the larger the number of classes the larger this will grow. Try increasing the `MaxPermSize` you're passing to the wscompile task and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Do you have an example of how this is set? I tried multiple options and didn't work.

Comment: @Java Guy Go to the page [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) and search for `MaxPermSize`.